# coldfusion - regex - because lazy doesnt work

Tags: regex, coldfusion

Trying to remove some code by regex where it follows the pattern

```
<cfif CheckMember.RecordCount gt 0>[SOME TEXT HERE ALL I KNOW IS IT DOENST CONTAIN A </cfif>]</cfif>
```

So i need to find the first occurrence of `</cfif>` after that first bit. Problem is lazy is not working, its just getting everything. Any way to get everything between some text and the first occurrence of a word?

I was hoping `<cfif CheckMember.RecordCount gt 0>.+?</cfif>` would work like it does in other engines.

Comment: thanks for the edit i noticed i didnt put the html tags in as text.

Comment: just for future reference, if you type xml without formatting it as code (by wrapping with ` or using 4 space indent) it wont show up.

Comment: Perhaps you need to escape some of your characters that are meaningful in a regex context: `<cfif CheckMember\.RecordCount gt 0>.+?<\/cfif>`. (Escaping the period probably doesn't matter in context, but I can see where the slash might cause problems.)

Comment: What regex engine are you using to match with?

Comment: What exactly are you wanting to remove? Just everything between `<cfif CheckMember.RecordCount gt 0>` and `</cfif>` ?

Comment: The regex engine is coldfusion so the same as java. Im wanting to get rid of everything including hte matched portions, but only up to and including the first occurrence of </cfif>

Comment: **ColdFusion is NOT the same regex engine as Java.** Are you using the refind/rematch/rereplace functions, or are you creating objects from the java.util.regex package, or are you using something else?

Comment: @PeterBoughton using re- functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason what you wrote shouldn't work (aside from `.` not matching newlines without the appropriate flag set), but in general lazy matching is not the most efficient way to do things, and using a pattern like this is likely to be better:

```
<cfif CheckMember\.RecordCount gt 0>(?:[^<]++|<(?!/cfif>))*</cfif>
```

The key part being:

```
(?:
    [^<]++
|
    <(?!/cfif>)
)*
```

i.e. not an angle bracket, or an angle-bracket that isn't starting a `</cfif>` sequence.

(Depending on what regex engine you are using, you may need to change the possessive `++` to a simple greedy `+`)

Comment: Ahhh this is not working either. Its not matching anything. This regex engine is just messed up.

Comment: Since you're using re~ functions, change the `++` to `+` - if it still doesn't work, test with `<cfif[^>]+>(?:[^<]+|<(?!/cfif>))*</cfif>` to see if the condition is what you think it is.

Comment: Yea i tried by changing to nonpossessive then I fudged it up a bit and used <cfif CheckMember\.RecordCount gt 0>(.(?!</cfif>))+.</cfif> which also works in other engines but not the coldfusion one.

Comment: I can see the text but this has to run through code on 200 sites so I need to be sure it removes it even if it was slightly modified (extra character or space somewhere) barring that nobody added any extra `<cfif>`s

Comment: Well `\s+` and `\s*` in suitable places will help with that, and make sure it's case-insensitive too. Also, might be safer doing it in an IDE with preview functionality?

Comment: No reason for CF to fail though - have you confirmed the input is what is expected?

Comment: Yea thats what im finding strange. Ive only been pre-checking patterns in Notepad++ but may need to move into printing the matches so I can see what it is finding exactly. I wonder if lazy match across new line is causing the error.

Comment: I am inclined to believe there is a problem in your code, not the regex engine as my 'answer' was tested using ColdFusion 9

Comment: Some other code was scrubbing the <> symbols. I worked around with no problems now. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work for what you are looking to do

```
<cfif CheckMember.RecordCount gt 0>.*?</cfif>
```

Comment: so the mandatory 1 match (+) modifier doesnt play nice with lazy matching in coldfusion?

Comment: unfortunately this isnt working. CF/Java regex engine seems to ignore the lazy modifier

Comment: I tested that in CF using the string you provided and it worked as expected.